# While uninstalling a software using Chef infra client failed after 10 minutes 43 seconds

Tags: chef-infra

While uninstalling a software using Chef infra client failed after 10 minutes 43 seconds.
I am getting Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed : windows_package error.

Here is the code i am trying to execute

```
windows_package 'SDL Tridion Sites 9.5' do
   action :remove
   options '-s'                
   notifies :reboot_now, 'reboot[user created now reboot requested]', :immediately
 end

 reboot 'user created now reboot requested' do
   action :nothing
   reason 'Chef will continue after reboot user added' 
 end
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't know much about "SDL Tridion Sites 9.5", but have you tried passing `options '-s -uninstall'`?

Comment: Thanks seshadri,
I have tried -s option - it did not work.
but not tried above mentioned options '-s -uninstall' by you.
will give a try.